# Linear Integer Arithmetic Satisfiability with Three Literals

Tags: lo.logic, sat, boolean-formulas

I'm stuck on trying to find an unsatisfiable conjunction of the form $a \wedge b \wedge c$ where:

- $a \wedge b$ is satisfiable
- $a \wedge c$ is satisfiable
- $b \wedge c$ is satisfiable
- $a, b, c$ are boolean literals from Linear Integer Arithmetic, i.e. $x \leq y$, $\neg(3 = 5)$, $z = z$, etc.

Is there no such case that this is possible (is there a proof for it), or am I just missing an obvious example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x< y) \land (y < z) \land (z < x)$